# GeoServer GetMap with geopackage very slow (with high zoom levels)

Tags: geoserver, performance, geopackage, large-datasets, getmap

I have a GeoServer instance and have imported multiple high res tiff files as layers and created a layergroup from the layers. When I call the WMS endpoint with a specified bbox and the geopackage format, it can take multiple hours to get the geopackage from the server. It appears when my gridset includes zoom levels 19 or above is when I begin to see the time increase exponentially. A jpeg or PNG returns quickly.

Are there optimizations that can be made either to the query or to how we are organizing our layers that could help? Even if the bbox provided is within a single layer, the query against the layer group is extremely slow.

Example query: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&layers=TestWKSP:TestLGroup&bbox=627883.09857,8299208.89693,628180.15347,8299506.25009&width=500&height=500&srs=EPSG:32735&format=geopackage&format_options=min_zoom:8;max_zoom:21;tileset_name:neighborhood&transparent=true

Comment: You can't compare with the png or jpeg outputformat because GeoPackage output is producing all the tiles which are needed to cover the given BBOX at zoom levels from min_zoom to max_zoom. But the speed of the GeoPackage output feels still quite bad. Have you calculated what is the resolution at zoom level 21 with your srs (EPSG:32735)? The number of tiles to generate may be rather high. Exponential increase in time is normal  because number of tiles is four times higher for each new zoom level.

Comment: It makes sense that the geopackage cannot be compared to jpeg/png. I wonder if there is any way to make the geopackage plugin make use of caching? For now I will see if we can build smaller groups to query against. Each of the tiff files is over 1gb in size (10cm accuracy) and the layer group has 100+ layers. So that's a lot of work for geoserver to be doing.

Comment: are your images compressed and tiled with overviews so that GeoServer can read them easily? See http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: Also try using an image mosaic rather than a Layer Group to merge multiple geotiffs

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The images are not currently compressed and tiles with overviews. I will work on that and also use an image mosaic and compare the results. Very much appreciated!